# How to fix user account block when logging in with Github in Vercel?

Tags: github, vercel

I've created and deployed multiple projects on Vercel with Github repository, and currently I've been working on a project and created a new account on Github and pushed my code on my repository. after that I've tried to signup to my Vercel with the new Github account, but when I do that it displays an error:

> This user account is blocked. Contact registration@vercel.com for more information.

I have no idea as to why this is happening and how to fix this. Can anyone please explain this and help me to fix this?